# Why when I timeout a function a defer is not called?

Tags: go, concurrency

When I add a defer in a function I expect that it will be always called when the function ends.
I noticed that it does not happen when the function is times out.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func service1(ctx context.Context, r *Registry) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 100*time.Millisecond)
    defer func() {
        r.Unset("service 1")
    }()
    r.Set("service 1")
    go service2(ctx, r)

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        cancel()
        break
    }
 }

 func service2(ctx context.Context, r *Registry) {
    defer func() {
        r.Unset("service 2")
    }()

    r.Set("service 2")

    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 300)
 }

         type Registry struct {
    entries map[string]bool
 }

 func (r *Registry)Set(key string) {
    r.entries[key] = true
 }

 func (r *Registry)Unset(key string)  {
    r.entries[key] = false
 }

 func (r *Registry)Print() {
    for key, val := range r.entries  {
        fmt.Printf("%s -> %v\n", key, val)
    }
 }

 func NewRegistry() *Registry {
    r := Registry{}
    r.entries = make(map[string]bool)

    return &r
 }

func main() {
    r := NewRegistry()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Millisecond*200)

    go service1(ctx, r)
    // go service3(ctx, r)

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Printf("context err: %s\n", ctx.Err())
        cancel()
    }

    r.Print()
 }
```

In the example above, the defer in `service2()` is never called and that's why the output is:

```
service 1 -> false
service 2 -> true
```

instead of

```
service 1 -> false
service 2 -> false
```

I understand that timeout means "stop executing" but it's reasonable to me execute deferred code. I could not find any explanation of this behavior.

And the second part of the question - how to modify the service or `Registry` to be resistant to such situations?

Comment: race condition maybe? your r registry variable has no locking?

Comment: The `main` function calls `r.Print()` before `service2` returns. There's a data race on the map (run the program with  `go -race main.go` to view the races).

Comment: Your program may print anything, e.g. even  `service 1 -> hubbu bubba trallala` as it is malformed as it is racy.

Comment: "the defer in service2() is never called". Yes it is. Approximately 300 milliseconds after service2 starts running. "I understand that timeout means 'stop executing'". No, it does not, at least not regarding the context package. Cancelling a context doesn't do anything fancy; it simply closes a channel.

Comment: you are right! I misunderstood it. So how to solve the problem correctly? Should I introduce a channel and wait for a signal or add mutexes somehow?

Comment: Please put your code in the question. Playgrounds links are great, but should not be required to understand your question--especially considering external links tend to go stale eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer of 1st part

Say you have a function `f1()` which uses `defer` to call `f2()`, i.e. `defer f2()` . The fact is that the `f2` will be called if and only if `f1` completes even if a run-time panic occurs. More specifically, look at [go-defer](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/7#section6).

Now our concern is about using defer in goroutine. We also have to remember that a go-routine exits if it's parent function completes of exits.

So if we use `defer` in a go-routine function, then if the parent fuction completes or exits, then go-routine function must exit. Since it exits (not completes) the `defer` statement will not execute. It will be clear we draw the state of your program.
[image]
As you see,

- at 1st millisecond, `service1()` completes before others. So, `service2()` exits without executing `defer` statement and 'service 2' won't be set to `false`. Since `service1()` completes, it's `defer` will execute and 'service 1' will be set to `false`.
- at 2nd millisecond, the `main()` completes and program finishes.

So we see how this program executes.

### Answer of 2nd part

One possible solution i tried is increase time in `service1()` or decrease time in `service2()`.

Comment: I added timeouts to simulate the situation when `service2()` executes longer time than `service1()` to learn how to deal with such situations. So the answer for part 2 is not the answer to my question. But thanks for the explanation! Helped me a lot.

Comment: Did you mean that the timeout for `service2()` is less than timeout for `service1()`?

Comment: Not quite... I wanted to simulate a situation when `service1()` is running and defer is executed. However, the `service2()` is still running and then it timeouts. I'm thinking about buffered channels as a solution for the data condition you explained.

Comment: In that case did you call `service2()` from `service1()`? I/m just wanted to know.

Comment: correct! It looks like that -> `main()` -> `go service1()` ->`go service2()`

Comment: So, if you simulate a solution when `service1()` is running and defer is executed then how `service2()` is still in running. Cause it's parent is `service1()` as you said. So you can't go with this solution. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183198/discussion-between-shudipta-sharma-and-kabanek).